# Probability of losing more than 50 in flip coin

Tags: probability, gambling

You flip symetric coin 1000 times. For head you get 1\$ and for tail you lose 1\$. Estimate propability of losing more than 50\$.

My attempt:

$X-(1000-X)$ - is random variable of how much we win

$P(2X-1000<-50)=P(X<475)=1-P(X\ge475)$

Now i used markov inequality but it gives negative value so it doesn't make sens.

Comment: do you know Chernoff bounds?  Basically lift through the moment generating function, and apply markov inequality there.

Answer (score 1):

Markov's inequality predicts $\displaystyle \frac{500}{475}$ which is horrible. Talk about upper bound!

I'd recommend a normal/binomial approximation?

You have $E(X)=500$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{1000(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})}$, which means that $P(X<475)$ corresponds to a $z$ score below $-1.58$ and a probability of $0.057$.

Comment: I think i was supposed to use Markov's or Chebyshev's inequality, but was my reasoning correct?

Comment: @Szakul1 well it's good that you caught the error in markov's

Comment: but i think chebyshev's would be better suited here

Comment: you could have used the symmetric nature of the coin flips + the fact that no more than 1/k^2 can be k standard deviations away which would allow you to bound the probability at $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2(1.58)^2} = 0.200$ which isn't horrible, i'd suppose